# Extract information from a large XML file

Tags: xml

I need to get some urls from a large xml file.

Xml file has the below structure.

```
<Main>
 <Product>
  <Images>
   <URL>image1.jpg</URL>
   <URL>image2.jpg</URL>
   <URL>image3.jpg</URL>
   <URL>image4.jpg</URL>
  </Images>
 </Product>
```

......

I need to extract all the links into a text file.
Have any ideea on how to do this /?

Comment: Are you writing a program to do this, or looking for a tool that does it?

Comment: a tool will be great.

Comment: You need to tell us what operating system you're using.

Comment: i use windows but i have access to a centos vps also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Perl installed (or you can install it), you can use `xml_grep`, which comes with [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) (available in [Activestate Perl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl), or in [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) or of course on centOS).

```
xml_grep --text_only URL product_file.xml > url.txt
```

It can deal with very large files, since it works in stream mode.

Answer (score 1):

How about using XPath to retrieve the nodes you need? You could then write the contents of that list into a text file. Here's some code in C# that should do the job for you:

```
public static void Main(string[] Arguments)
{
    XmlDocument oXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    oXmlDocument.Load(@"XmlFile.xml");

    using (StreamWriter oStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(@"Output.txt")))
    {
        XmlNodeList oXmlNodeList = oXmlDocument.SelectNodes("//URL");

        oXmlNodeList.OfType<XmlNode>().ToList<XmlNode>().ForEach(m => oStreamWriter.WriteLine(m.InnerText));
    }
}
```

If the document is huge, it might be better to consider a SAX approach rather than using the DOM.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

do you only need the urls?

the given structure looks like the urls a associated to the image/product data? if you dont care about the other data and only need all urls, a regexp should be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example that should load the XML you've pasted. You'll need to add `System.Xml.Linq` because it uses [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). First we load the XML document using [`XDocument.Load(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299692(v=vs.110).aspx):

```cs
// Load the raw XML into an XDocument.
var doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(@"<Main>
 <Product>
  <Images>
   <URL>image1.jpg</URL>
   <URL>image2.jpg</URL>
   <URL>image3.jpg</URL>
   <URL>image4.jpg</URL>
  </Images>
 </Product>
</Main>"));
```

I use a [`StringReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and the example string, but you should change it to something that loads your XML file. For example, `XDocument.Load("C:\folder\file.xml")` will load a file (see [XDocument.Load(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181(v=vs.110).aspx)).

```
// Create a list to store the URLs in.
var urls = new List<string>();

// Get the <Main> element.
var mainNode = doc.Element("Main");

// Loop through the <Product> elements...
foreach (var productNode in mainNode.Elements("Product"))
{
    // Loop through the <Images> elements (if there's more than one).
    foreach (var imagesNode in productNode.Elements("Images"))
    {
        // Loop through the <URL> elements...
        foreach (var urlNode in imagesNode.Elements("URL"))
        {
            // The "Value" property is the text within the element.
            urls.Add(urlNode.Value);
        }
    }
}

// Write the URLs out to the Debug output.
foreach (var url in urls)
    Debug.WriteLine(url);
```

At this point, you'll have a list of URLs. If you want to write them to a file, here's an example:

```
// Create an output file.
using(var outputFile = File.Create("output.txt"))
{
    var writer = new StreamWriter(outputFile);
    foreach (var url in urls)
        writer.WriteLine(url);
}
```

You don't necessarily have to create the list and the write the list to the file like I did-- you could just write the URLs to the text file as you read them.

Let me know if there's anything else I can do to help.